# VB.NET unattended execution, no UI, no message boxes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010, unattended-processing

VB.NET 2010, Framework 3.5

An app that will run continuously and unattended on a server.  There is no user interface.  There is no human intervention.  What can one do to be sure that **no message boxes are displayed** if an unforeseen error or exception is thrown?

Comment: there really isnt. you need a try catch in the areas that are likely to throw an exception otherwise the JIT will kick in thus crashing your app and a dialog being shown. why would the app be unattended?

Comment: It processes data is it comes in, no one is there to click <Ok> and interact with it.

Comment: I think making the Application type a 'Windows Service' is what I am looking for

Comment: exactly. :) that is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a 'Windows Service' is what I am looking for